# Class __repr__ of a metaclass, not a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass, repr

I am aware of the ability to define a `'class repr'` by using a metaclass. However, I need the functionality of returning the metaclass with its own `__repr__` as such:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'Person class: {}'.format(cls.__name__)


class Person(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Person: {}, {}, {}'.format(self.name,
                                           self.age,
                                           self.job)


class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super(Employee, self).__init__(name, age, 'employee')


class Manager(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(name, age, 'manager')

m = Manager('bob', 79)
e = Employee('stephen', 25)
```

As expected, `type(e)` and `type(m)` return their respective `'Person class: ...'`, however, if I do `type(Employee)`, I get `<class '__main__.Meta'>`. I need this class to have its own `__repr__` as the actual implementation I am using consists of a base `Type` class with subclasses of `String`, `Number`, etc. Calling type on the instances works just fine, but since type may be also called on the class, I need a more 'user-friendly' return string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, nothing would prevent you from writting a meta-meta class with the `__repr__` for the metaclass itself:

```
In [2]: class MM(type):
   ...:     def __repr__(cls):
   ...:         return f"<metaclass {cls.__name__}"
   ...:      

In [3]: class M(type, metaclass=MM):
   ...:     def __repr__(cls):
   ...:         return f"<class {cls.__name__}>"
   ...:     

In [4]: class O(metaclass=M):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [5]: o = O()

In [6]: o
Out[6]: <<class O> at 0x7ff7e0089128>

In [7]: O
Out[7]: <class O>
```

The output of `repr(M)`:

```
In [8]: repr(M)
Out[8]: '<metaclass M'
```

(The confusing thing here is that `type` is also the metaclass for `type` itself - that is reflected here in that M does not inherit from `MM`, but rather, have it as its metaclass).

Comment: Could you add the output of `repr(M)`? This is the part I am looking for.

Comment: @NChauhan You should get in the habit of checking these things yourself.  Regardless, when I run this I see that `repr(M)` is `"<metaclass M"`

Comment: Creative! I should have checked this :-) Python metaclasses are, after all, also still classes.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution. Since my class structure (inheritance tree) is as follows, I just need to return the next class down:

```
MetaType: metaclass with __repr__
 |
Type: base class
 |
builtins: e.g. String, Number
```

So all I put in my code was this:

```
t = type(self.parse(args['object']))
# where 'self.parse' is the parsing method for the argument to my function
# where args['object'] is the object whose type is being returned
if t == MetaType:
    return Type
return t
```